# FORMULA SI O BUSCARV

Tags: excel

Qué tal.

Tengo una base con equis modelos de equipos pero necesito clasificarlos como gama alta y baja y que en la columna Y de como resultado el tipo de gama. Actualmente tengo dos tablas donde se especifica que modelo es de gama alta o baja.

Les anexo un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con la siguiente formula: =SI(K2=$Z$2:$Z$18,"GAMA ALTA","GAMA BAJA") pero solo me da como resultado GAMA BAJA, cuando no es un equipo que este dentro del listado.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería usar el CONTAR.SI. Cuenta si la gama de la fila aparece en la columna Z. Si el resultado es 0, es que es GAMA BAJA y en caso contrario, es GAMA ALTA.

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI($Z$2:$Z$18;K2)=0,"GAMA BAJA","GAMA ALTA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo que modifiques ligeramente la distribución de tu tabla para que puedas utilizar `BUSCARV()`. Sólo tienes que poner la gama del equipo a su lado en vez de encima (con un simple Ctrl+J puedes llenar hacia abajo los huecos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he resuelto con provincias y autonomías en vez de con equipos y gamas, pero es totalmente análogo, la fórmula resultante es exactamente la misma que necesitas:

```
=BUSCARV(A2;C$2:D18;2;0)
```

Espero que te resulte útil.